# Energy of a short time fourier transform involving father wavelets

Tags: fourier-transform, wavelets

Lots of definitions here.

My definition for the fourier transform is 
$$\widehat{f}(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-iwt}dt$$

$1$) I must show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|Sf(\mu, \varepsilon)|^2d\varepsilon=2\pi$$
where $Sf(\mu,\epsilon)$ is the short-time fourier transform with window function $g$
$$Sf(\mu, \varepsilon)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(t-\mu)e^{-i\varepsilon t}dt$$
and in this case the function is $f(t)=e^{i\phi(t)}$  where $\phi(t)$ is the father wavelet defined as
$$|\widehat{\phi}(w)|^2=\int_{1}^{\infty}|\widehat{\Psi}(sw)|^2\frac{ds}{s}=\int_{|w|}^{\infty}\frac{|\widehat{\Psi}(\varepsilon)|^2}{\varepsilon}d\varepsilon$$
where $\Psi$ is the Mexican hat wavelet defined as the negative second derivative of a Gaussian
$$\Psi(t)=\frac{2}{\pi^{1/4}\sqrt{3\sigma}}\Big(1-\frac{t^2}{\sigma^2}\Big)\text{exp}\Big(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)$$

$2$) I also must show that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varepsilon |Sf(\mu, \varepsilon)|^2d\varepsilon = 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi'(t)|g(t-\mu)|^2dt$$

I don't know how to go about solving $2$) but it probably involves $1$). For $1$) The Short time fourier transform is the fourier transform of $f(t)g(t-\mu)$ so by Plancherel's identity I would just need to prove
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)g(t-\mu)|^2\:dt=1$$
but I don't know how to proceed. Something else that might help are the following, although I would need a proof for the second theorem.
$$2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|^2\:dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|Sf(\mu, \varepsilon)|^2\:d\varepsilon \: d\mu$$
$$2\pi ||\phi||_2^2=||\widehat{\phi}||_2^2=1$$